# Button not becoming active on page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some code (found on CodePen).

This is the orginal and how its supposed to work :

http://codepen.io/oknoblich/pen/qcsih

When I try and test the code out , the buttons dont become active / selected.

My code :

Html Page :  : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw80J_dEB_59emFhRlM0eUdhMGc/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're going to have to post *small* snippets of code where you're having problems.  The codepen example has about 150 lines and your page has over 800.

Comment: Im not entirely sure where the problems is . If you view my code as an actually page the buttons dont actually become active or selected . I think it may be the javascript.

Comment: Anything in the console log?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined   line 475

Comment: Have you imported jquery?

Comment: Wow , i feel realy dumb . Thanks @Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined line 475` you don't have jQuery loaded properly.

Try loading jquery by placing this above your scripts at the bottom of the page:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0-rc1/jquery.js"></script>
```

With that, this will be pulling from a CDN.  You can also upload jquery to your server and pull from there if you'd like.